# JQuery append value set null before setting another

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, append

here I'm using bootstrap modal. When it popup I set a title dynamically by combining existing value (Upload Your File).

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" style="font-size: 130%">Upload Your File </h4>
</div>
```

here is my function

```
<script>
clearBn.on("click", function(){
var link = $(this).attr('href');
var hashPosition = link.indexOf('#'); //Get the position of '#'
var product = link.substring(hashPosition + 3);         
$(".modal-header #myModalLabel").after( product );
});
</script>
```

Here I'm doing is split value in the `href` and set that value to `modal-header`. Then I again do that it shows the previous appended value and new value like this

1st time:

> Upload Your File
>
> ABC

2nd time:

> Upload Your File
>
> ABCXYZ

Here I want is clear ABC and put XYZ while **Upload Your File** text stay remain there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will be helpful

```
var _newText = "Upload Your File "+product
$(".modal-header #myModalLabel").text(_newText);
```

else you can modify the HTML and keep a specific DOM element to show the file name. Then select that DOM & just put `product` as text in that specified DOM

Comment: Good solution This solved my problem. I never thought like this kind of thing. I tried to append with Html content `Upload Your File` because that content has a style and my appending text goes down and show.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help:

```
$("#myModalLabel").reset();
```